# Event listeners do not work on newly added table columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a basic HTML table that gets loaded. The structure differs based on and uploaded CSV file's content. The table columns need to be drag-able (for which I use a plugin called Dragtable). I then have methods to add rows and columns. The add column method looks like this:

```
function addCol(tblId) {
 var tblHeadObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tHead;
 for (var h=0; h < tblHeadObj.rows.length; h++) {
    var newTH = document.createElement('th');
    tblHeadObj.rows[h].appendChild(newTH);
    colCount = (tblHeadObj.rows[h].cells.length);
    newTH.innerHTML = 'Col ' + colCount;
 }

 var tblBodyObj = document.getElementById(tblId).tBodies[0];
 for (var i=0; i<tblBodyObj.rows.length; i++) {
    var newCell = tblBodyObj.rows[i].insertCell(-1);
    newCell.innerHTML = "*null*";
 }
}
```

The problem is that when I add a new column, I can no longer drag that column to place it in a different spot. I also have an onclick handler for table headings which allow the user to delete a column when he clicks on the th element. This also does not work on newly added columns. Basically, all event listeners are not added on new columns.

I have tried hiding and showing the table and the page, which does not work. I think I need a way for the table to be refreshed, but cannot find something that works.

Something like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById("grid");
table.refresh ();
```

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or is there something wrong with the way I add columns which could be the reason why the event listeners are not attached?

**EDIT**

The  delete column method is below: (**Edited** with proper event delegation) **This fixed the problem for the delete column method. I am still unable to drag and sort new columns though**

```
$("table").delegate("th:not(:first)", "click", function() {
   var index = this.cellIndex;
   $(this).closest('table').find('tr').each(function() {
     this.removeChild(this.cells[ index ]);
   });  
}
```

Regarding the Dragtable column sorting, I just add the draggable class to my table. I'm not sure how the event listener looks:

```
<table id = "grid" class="draggable"></table>
```

Comment: Again event delegation!

Comment: You have to use jQuery's on() method, with delegation, to account for items added to the DOM after it is rendered the first time. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Please post the code for your event listeners so we can show you how to modify them to use event delegation instead.

Comment: Is this question tagged with jQuery because you want a jQuery solution, because I see no jQuery in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I've updated my question.

Comment: I've updated my original question and used event delegation to get the delete column method working. The biggest problem still remains though: I cannot drag and re-position newly added columns with the dragtable plugin. Any thoughts on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event delegation for this. What you should do is add an event listener to the table itself, which checks the `.target` property of the event object to see if the event is targeted at a heading and takes the appropriate action.

Aside from the event delegation approach, another easy fix you could make is to simply attach the handler when you add a new row:

```
newTH.addEventListener("click", function(){
     //this should be your event listener
})
```

<sub>*As j08691 has pointed out, you may have tagged jQuery mistakenly, so I am not adding any jQuery code for now*</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much, I've managed to get the delete method working (see edited question). The drag-able columns feature is however still not working, which is the most important functionality of the site. I am desperate for help. Anything you could add please?